# Substring Count in Twig

Tags: count, twig, substring

I am looking to use [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) in Twig, does anything exist already? I want to perform something like this;

```
<?php
$text = 'This is a test';
echo strlen($text); // 14

echo substr_count($text, 'is'); // 2
```

I can do an extension but it seems this might be something built in already that I have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for an extension

```
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class SubStrCountExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('substr_count', array($this, 'substr_count')),
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'substr_count_extension';
    }

    public function substr_count($str, $char)
    {
        return substr_count($str, $char);
    }
}
```

And in `services.yml`

```
app.twig_extension.substr_count_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\SubStrCountExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: just a suggestion, but I'd rename your class to something more general so that you can add multiple functions/filters into your custom class, unless you are planning to all your custom functions/filters in their own individual classes.

Comment: Good shout! I do this now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

How about this?

```
{%set count = text|split('is')|length-1 %}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16688233)

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Why?

Comment: why?  topic starter asked about the way to count substrings in string with twig. This 1 row of code does this. What's wrong with this?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It works (other than some edge cases that can be accounted for with a little extra logic) and doesn't use an extension, as specified in the question.

Comment: This absolutely worked for me. I don't even think there are edge cases for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exist in the list of Twig [functions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/index.html) or [filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/index.html).

You'll have to write your own custom function/filter or try a [package](https://packagist.org/packages/umpirsky/twig-php-function) (note; I've never used this package so can't comment on it, but was on the first page of Google results).

Answer (score 0):

I use solution in Symfony 3.2.8 but in the description does not say this block of code should is inside : **services**
If you does not make show this error:
There is no extension able to load the configuration for .....

This code should is inside **services** this is correct:

```
services:

app.twig_extension.substr_count_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\SubStrCountExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Finally, the correct use in twig is:

```
tu placa es: {{substr_count(datos.picoyplaca,4)}}
```

Regards